# CSS Grid - How to make items responsive

Tags: css, css-grid

I was trying to make the 2 items (box1 and box2) responsive on small screen, but I couldn't seem to figure it out. Please help. Thanks!

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style>
      body{
          background: lightblue;
        }
      .container{
          padding:10px;
          display: grid;
          background: lightyellow;
          width:100%;
          grid-gap:5px;
          justify-content:center;
          grid-auto-flow: column;
          grid-auto-columns: 300px 100px;
        }
      .box1{
          background: lightgray;
          min-height:150px;
        }
      .box2{
          background: lightgreen;
          min-height:150px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="box box1">BOX 1</div>
      <div class="box box2">BOX 2</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use percentages instead of pixel values

Comment: @Paulie_D What I would like to do is to have boxes stack over each other on small screen with those values as max-width. Is that possible?

Comment: That's a different question. I'd suggest you ask a NEW question if that's what you want but the answer would be a media query and change the `grid-auto:columns` value in it,

Answer (score 0):

You've told the columns to be a **fixed width**...so they're naturally not responsive.

Use percentage or fractional values instead.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  background: lightblue;
}

.container {
  padding: 10px;
  display: grid;
  background: lightyellow;
  width: 100%;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-auto-columns: 3fr 1fr;
}

.box1 {
  background: lightgray;
  min-height: 150px;
}

.box2 {
  background: lightgreen;
  min-height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box box1">BOX 1</div>
  <div class="box box2">BOX 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
          grid-auto-columns: 300px 100px;
```

in that line above you use ABSOLUTE sizes. If you want them to be responsive use % instead of px.
something like

```
              grid-auto-columns: 30% 10%;
```

Answer (score 0):

Any time you use fixed pixel widths, your elements will remain at that size and not be responsive.

The quick and easy solution to this is to switch to percentage widths, which tells the element to be a proportion of its container's size. Assuming the container is itself responsive, then this will make your elements change size according to the width of the screens. You need to do this all the way through your CSS, as any fixed sizes further up the element tree could stop everything inside from responding.

However, a naive percentage figure is often not a perfect solution, because things may not look right with the same proportions at lower screen sizes. For example, a three-column layout may shrink down, but it will look very squashed on a small mobile phone screen.

There are a bunch of solutions to this, and the exact answer will depend on your page design and your preferences.

First up, consider using `min-width` and `max-width` with pixel sizes to limit the sizes of your elements. These CSS values will override the percentage if the percentage figure causes them to go above or below the max or min width that you specify. This can be helpful for preventing things from getting exessively squashed or stretched out while still responding appropriately within the desired range.

Next, you need to know about Media Queries. This is a CSS feature that allows you to specify CSS that is only applied when the browser size is within a specified range. (Media queries can do a lot more than this, but I'll leave it to you to investigate them further)

An example might help here:

```
@media(max-width:600px) {
    .container {
        grid-auto-flow: unset;
        grid-auto-columns: unset;
    }
}
```

The example above uses a media query to switch off your columns if the browser width is 600 pixels or less. For narrow browsers, a column-based layout may not be appropriate, so switching away from it at low resolutions is often a good idea.